# Spring security does not allow CSS or JS resources to be loaded

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The resource is under src/main/resources/static/css or src/main/resources/static/js, I'm using spring boot, and the class of security is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index", "/quizStart")
//              .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
//      http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
//              .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("test")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

It works well (resources can be loaded) when I access "/index" from browser, however, if I uncomment the four lines in the class, resources can not be loaded, the four lines means:

```
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index", "/quizStart")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
            .permitAll();
```

Could anyone help with this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You probably want to make sure to have your directory containing those items set as permitAll.

Here's an excerpt from my spring security context file. Under the resources directory, I have js, css, and images folders which are given permissions by this line.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: thanks for your notification, I add line `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll();` into `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` and then it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.  I used a pretty sweet maven archetype I found online to generate this project, and it started out with a working, spring MVC, spring security, JPA, and thymeleaf project.  It's got a very good spring java config setup by default, you might want to check it out:  https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype.

Comment: It's really good to me and I have join the watched list, will have a try later, thanks again~

Comment: Where should this file be located? Any examples?

Comment: Spring Boot will, by default, permit access to `/css/**`, `/js/**`, `/images/**`, and `/**/favicon.ico`.

Comment: @Junjie Thanks a lot bro! :D

Answer (score 18):

For some reason, this did not work for me:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();
```

I had to add this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Also, this line has to be after the code which restrics access.

Comment: In this way you removed all security, the '.anyRequest().permitAll()' will permit all requests, you must find the right path to your resources and use it.
If you use spring security, then usually anyRequest() has to be authenticated()

Comment: you might as well not even do the first antmatcher then lol

Answer (score 13):

Add following

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").anyRequest();
    }
```

Comment: .anyRequest(); will block your site

Comment: @Yogesh : Worked..Kudos, that's exactly the issue which I was having. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12):

you can also use directly like "/*.js" for specific file or "/resources/**" for directory

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and the `permitAll()` solution didn't work for me. I added the following `@Override`method to my `WebSecurityConfig`class.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/icon/**");
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changing access to "permitAll" didn't help.
I created a new http pattern where I set security to "none" and then I was able to download the css and js files without authentication.

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me. The /home (which will bring up the login page) and error messages do not need authentication. All the resources are permitAll, and the /main url is authenticated. Any other url (eg. /users /customers etc..) would need to be added as isAuthenticated()

```
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAnonymous()"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/error*" access="isAnonymous()"/>      
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/main" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />     
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/fonts/**" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Answer (score 0):

.antMatchers("/*.js", "/*.css").permitAll()