# Setup Spring security to redirect user to login page if not authenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring boot application with Spring security.

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368535/when-spring-security-enabled-resoucescss-or-js-cant-be-loaded), but in my case I want to redirect the user to the `login` page if he's not authenticated when he tries to access **any** page of the application.

The following image shows the architecture of the application:

[image: Architecture of the app]

My config class looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

With this configuration, no resource will be loaded.
How can I configure my project to redirect the user to the login page if he's not authenticated **and** at the same time having my resources folder loaded?

Comment: Where is your login page?  The screenshot above doesn't show its location in your project.

Comment: The login page is in the `templates.pages` folder.

Answer (score 5):

plz checkout `configure` method

```
@Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login");
  }
```

and `implements WebMvcConfigurer` Class like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
  }
}
```

`addResourceHandlers` means find resources in /static.

Comment: The line
    `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();`
only allows me to access the page at localhost:8080/resources/ without being redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Spring security is not allowing your css when a "GET" request to it is made allow it by changing the following line to the next line

this line = .antMatchers("/*.js").permitAll()

this line = .antMatchers("/*.js", "/*.css").permitAll()

Answer (score 0):

Update your method by using `authenticated()` like below.

```
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/login*").
              .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/*.js").permitAll()
              .permitAll()
              .anyRequest()
              .authenticated()
              .and()
              .formLogin();
        }
```

Refer [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login)

Comment: This allows me, indeed to redirect my user to the login page, but it still doesn't load the css files in the `ressources` folder...

Comment: updated the answer..pls check once added .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/*.js").permitAll()

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my login page before authentication, I found it and resolved my problem by overrode this method in SecurityConfig

```
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
  }
```

afterward login page knew .js and .css