# URL redirect in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi guys I want that I have a post method in spring controller
But user hits url request directly from a browser then user gets nothing.
So how can I redirect this to login page in spring mvc.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description

> But user hits url request directly from a browser then user gets
>   nothing

When user hitting a `URL`from browser, it should be a `GET` request but you said you have `POST` request there. That's why nothing happens(should give

> `GET` not supported

in browser though).
`POST` method requests server to process submitted form data.
To achieve that, you have to declare a `GET` method for that `URL` in your controller side and return your resource(view) to the user and then user will get that after hitting that `URL`. After that you can perform `POST` request from user side(i.e. form data submission).

In one line: Your `POST` request will be `GET` in controller side if you want to just what you want.

Please let me know if I can assist more.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should look for security instead of look for "redirects", you can cool at this question for reference :

[link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610122/setup-spring-security-to-redirect-user-to-login-page-if-not-authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible to make POST request from the browser.

You can find some other approaches [fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome)