# Spring Security cannot Access External JavaScript

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working with Spring Security and when I am trying to use external javascript or even webjars, security blocks access.

I've tried adding some javascript to my webpage like this:
*header.html*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.4.0/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.min.js"></script>
```

My Security Config looks like this (notice the "/webjars/**", "/*.js", "/**.js").permitAll()):

*AppConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
    return new LogoutController();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationController authenticationController() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JwkProvider jwkProvider = new JwkProviderBuilder(domain).build();
    return AuthenticationController.newBuilder(domain, clientId, clientSecret)
            .withJwkProvider(jwkProvider)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/callback", "/login", "/", "/*.png", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/bibliographies", "/bibliographies/*", "/api/**", "/webjars/**", "/*.js", "/**.js").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()).permitAll();
}
```

On loading the webpage from which I want to access the javascript I get the following Exception:

> 2020-01-18 16:38:39.941 DEBUG 7824 --- [nio-3000-exec-4]
>   o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is
>   anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
>
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
>   denied    at
>   org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
>   ~[spring-security-core-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
>   ~[spring-security-core-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   [spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   [spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   [spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   [spring-security-web-4.2.12.RELEASE.jar:4.2.12.RELEASE]

Other matchers I've declared such as "/api/**" are available without logging in, however my own security is blocking me from accessing *.js* files, even though my matchers seem ok.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You could potentially keep a local copy of the js file(s) under resources with your existing Spring Security configurations.

Comment: Can you update your pom.xml that contains the js dependency?

Comment: don't think the js-files are the problem, have you tried to leave them out?

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
```

in your context file. Here, resources is the directory where all JS files are located.

You can refer to this link:
[Spring security does not allow CSS or JS resources to be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368535/spring-security-does-not-allow-css-or-js-resources-to-be-loaded)